# Serializing (nested) data structures in a human-readable format

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel, serialization

I am reinventing the wheel to write a function that serializes a (nested) data structure human readably. The default output is deliberately similar to that of `json.dumps(var, indent=4)`, and I did my best to mimic the format of `json`s output.

But the output is fundamentally different from `json`. More specifically, the data types of the dictionary keys are preserved and all data types that can be valid dictionary keys are unchanged. For instance, `int` keys won't become `str` and `tuple` keys are allowed in this format whereas in `json` `tuple` keys are impossible. And dictionary keys aren't indented, because I don't use nested data structures as keys.

And all the values and/or elements retain their data types, for instance `True`, `False`, `None` won't become `true`, `false`, `null`.

I built my function using `repr`, but this is not `repr`. `repr` supports all data types defined in one section and the output is not indented, and the data types of the containers themselves are unchanged. But this function doesn't support all data types defined in one section and instead support only the builtin container data types `(dict, frozenset, list, set, tuple)` and their subclasses. The containers are "promoted" to the data type in the supported data types which they inherited from. Only the data types that aren't considered containers (the data types that can't be nested) are retained. And the output is far more human readable than `repr`.

I wrote this function to serialize nested dictionaries with `int` and `tuple` keys human readably, to store the data on the hard drive, so that I can load them later using `ast.literal_eval`. I want to allow `int` keys and I have to store `dict`s with `tuple` keys.

### Code

```py
from typing import Union

def represent(obj: Union[dict, frozenset, list, set, tuple], indent: int=4) -> str:
    supported = (dict, frozenset, list, set, tuple)
    singles = (frozenset, list, set, tuple)
    if not isinstance(obj, supported):
        raise TypeError('argument `obj` should be an instance of a built-in container data type')
    if not isinstance(indent, int):
        raise TypeError('argument `indent` should be an `int`')
    if indent <= 0:
        raise ValueError('argument `indent` should be greater than 0')
    if indent % 4:
        raise ValueError('argument `indent` should be a multiple of 4')
    ls = list()
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        start, end = '{}'
        for k, v in sorted(obj.items()):
            if not isinstance(v, supported):
                item = ' '*indent + repr(k) + ': ' + repr(v)
            else:
                item = ' '*indent + repr(k) + ': ' + represent(v, indent+4)
            ls.append(item)
    elif isinstance(obj, singles):
        enclosures = {
            0: ('frozenset({', '})'),
            1: '[]', 2: '{}', 3: '()'
        }
        index = 0
        for i in singles:
            if isinstance(obj, i):
                break
            index += 1
        start, end = enclosures[index]
        if index in (0, 2):
            obj = sorted(obj)
        for i in obj:
            if not isinstance(i, supported):
                item = ' '*indent + repr(i)
            else:
                item = represent(i, indent+4)
            ls.append(item)
    return start + '\n' + ',\n'.join(ls) + '\n' + ' ' * (indent - 4) + end
```

## Example

```py
import json
var = {1: {1: {1: {1: {1: {1: 0}, 2: 0}, 2: {1: 0}, 3: 0},
   2: {1: {1: 0}, 2: 0},
   3: {1: 0}},
  2: {1: {1: {1: 0}, 2: 0}, 2: {1: 0}, 3: 0},
  3: {1: {1: 0}, 2: 0}},
 2: {1: {1: {1: {1: 0}, 2: 0}, 2: {1: 0}, 3: 0},
  2: {1: {1: 0}, 2: 0},
  3: {1: 0}},
 3: {1: {1: {1: 0}, 2: 0}, 2: {1: 0}, 3: 0}}


dumped = json.dumps(var, indent=4)
repred = represent(var)

print('dumped:')
print(dumped)
print('repred:')
print(repred)

print(f'{(eval(dumped) == var)=}')
print(f'{(eval(repred) == var)=}')

var1 = {'a': {'a': {'a': [0, 0, 0], 'b': [0, 0, 1], 'c': [0, 0, 2]},
  'b': {'a': [0, 0, 1], 'b': [0, 1, 1], 'c': [0, 1, 2]},
  'c': {'a': [0, 0, 2], 'b': [0, 1, 2], 'c': [0, 2, 2]}},
 'b': {'a': {'a': [0, 0, 1], 'b': [0, 1, 1], 'c': [0, 1, 2]},
  'b': {'a': [0, 1, 1], 'b': [1, 1, 1], 'c': [1, 1, 2]},
  'c': {'a': [0, 1, 2], 'b': [1, 1, 2], 'c': [1, 2, 2]}},
 'c': {'a': {'a': [0, 0, 2], 'b': [0, 1, 2], 'c': [0, 2, 2]},
  'b': {'a': [0, 1, 2], 'b': [1, 1, 2], 'c': [1, 2, 2]},
  'c': {'a': [0, 2, 2], 'b': [1, 2, 2], 'c': [2, 2, 2]}}}

print(represent(var1))
```

```
dumped:
{
    "1": {
        "1": {
            "1": {
                "1": {
                    "1": {
                        "1": 0
                    },
                    "2": 0
                },
                "2": {
                    "1": 0
                },
                "3": 0
            },
            "2": {
                "1": {
                    "1": 0
                },
                "2": 0
            },
            "3": {
                "1": 0
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "1": {
                "1": {
                    "1": 0
                },
                "2": 0
            },
            "2": {
                "1": 0
            },
            "3": 0
        },
        "3": {
            "1": {
                "1": 0
            },
            "2": 0
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "1": {
            "1": {
                "1": {
                    "1": 0
                },
                "2": 0
            },
            "2": {
                "1": 0
            },
            "3": 0
        },
        "2": {
            "1": {
                "1": 0
            },
            "2": 0
        },
        "3": {
            "1": 0
        }
    },
    "3": {
        "1": {
            "1": {
                "1": 0
            },
            "2": 0
        },
        "2": {
            "1": 0
        },
        "3": 0
    }
}
repred:
{
    1: {
        1: {
            1: {
                1: {
                    1: {
                        1: 0
                    },
                    2: 0
                },
                2: {
                    1: 0
                },
                3: 0
            },
            2: {
                1: {
                    1: 0
                },
                2: 0
            },
            3: {
                1: 0
            }
        },
        2: {
            1: {
                1: {
                    1: 0
                },
                2: 0
            },
            2: {
                1: 0
            },
            3: 0
        },
        3: {
            1: {
                1: 0
            },
            2: 0
        }
    },
    2: {
        1: {
            1: {
                1: {
                    1: 0
                },
                2: 0
            },
            2: {
                1: 0
            },
            3: 0
        },
        2: {
            1: {
                1: 0
            },
            2: 0
        },
        3: {
            1: 0
        }
    },
    3: {
        1: {
            1: {
                1: 0
            },
            2: 0
        },
        2: {
            1: 0
        },
        3: 0
    }
}
(eval(dumped) == var)=False
(eval(repred) == var)=True
{
    'a': {
        'a': {
            'a': [
                0,
                0,
                0
            ],
            'b': [
                0,
                0,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                0,
                0,
                2
            ]
        },
        'b': {
            'a': [
                0,
                0,
                1
            ],
            'b': [
                0,
                1,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                0,
                1,
                2
            ]
        },
        'c': {
            'a': [
                0,
                0,
                2
            ],
            'b': [
                0,
                1,
                2
            ],
            'c': [
                0,
                2,
                2
            ]
        }
    },
    'b': {
        'a': {
            'a': [
                0,
                0,
                1
            ],
            'b': [
                0,
                1,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                0,
                1,
                2
            ]
        },
        'b': {
            'a': [
                0,
                1,
                1
            ],
            'b': [
                1,
                1,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                1,
                1,
                2
            ]
        },
        'c': {
            'a': [
                0,
                1,
                2
            ],
            'b': [
                1,
                1,
                2
            ],
            'c': [
                1,
                2,
                2
            ]
        }
    },
    'c': {
        'a': {
            'a': [
                0,
                0,
                2
            ],
            'b': [
                0,
                1,
                2
            ],
            'c': [
                0,
                2,
                2
            ]
        },
        'b': {
            'a': [
                0,
                1,
                2
            ],
            'b': [
                1,
                1,
                2
            ],
            'c': [
                1,
                2,
                2
            ]
        },
        'c': {
            'a': [
                0,
                2,
                2
            ],
            'b': [
                1,
                2,
                2
            ],
            'c': [
                2,
                2,
                2
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am mainly concerned about performance and memory consumption, and I want the function to execute as fast as possible while utilizing as little RAM as possible. How can it be more efficient?

### Update

Actually sorting the items while serializing the dictionaries does introduce bugs that somehow change the data represented, breaking the original association between the key value pairs, and this is definitely not intended.

Removing the `sorted` calls eliminates the bug, I have fixed my copy of the code but as this is code review and I have received answers I won't edit code posted above (lest the update be rolled back), so I decided to point this out.

More specifically,

This snippet:

```py
if isinstance(obj, dict):
    start, end = '{}'
    for k, v in sorted(obj.items()):
        if not isinstance(v, supported):
            item = ' '*indent + repr(k) + ': ' + repr(v)
        else:
            item = ' '*indent + repr(k) + ': ' + represent(v, indent+4)
        ls.append(item)
```

***MUST*** be changed to:

```py
if isinstance(obj, dict):
    start, end = '{}'
    for k, v in obj.items():
        if not isinstance(v, supported):
            item = ' '*indent + repr(k) + ': ' + repr(v)
        else:
            item = ' '*indent + repr(k) + ': ' + represent(v, indent+4)
        ls.append(item)
```

I now think sorting the collections while serializing them to be a terrible practice, but I don't know if this bug also affects nested `frozenset`s too (`set`s can't be nested because `set`s are mutable therefore unhashable), I haven't tested yet, but I recommend dropping the `sorted` calls on `frozenset` and `set` too (`frozenset`s can be nested inside `set`s and `frozenset`s).

### Update

---

Please review the latest version:
[Serializing (nested) data structures in a human-readable format with all bugs fixed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/269247/serializing-nested-data-structures-in-a-human-readable-format-with-all-bugs-fi)

Comment: One small remark: if each level of indent has the same offset (in your case 4 characters per indent), then I would abstract that number of characters away. For example, rename the `indent` parameter of the `respresent` function to `indentLevel` or `indentCount` or something along those lines, and define a function `createIndent(indentLevel: int) -> str` which returns `' ' * 4 * indentLevel`. (Naming is perhaps not the best yet, but you get the idea). Then replace all `' '*indent` in your code by a call to that function, or call the function once and store the result in a variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few things I noticed:

---

Since `supported` is a superset of `singles` I would recommend the following assignment:

```
singles = (frozenset, list, set, tuple)
supported = (dict, *singles)
```

This of course only makes sense if the two are also logically connected which I'd say is true here.

---

The assignment `start, end = '{}'` seems unintuitive to me, since string-unpacking isn't commonly used as far as I know.

I'd recommend `start, end = '{', '}'` if you want to stick to the one-liner or even better:

```
start = '{'
end = '}'
```

---

When traversing the nested data structures you always call your function with `indent=indent + 4`, regardless of the desired indent by the user. You should probably adjust that to match the user's preference (you might also want to allow indents that are not divisible by 4, e.g. indent-increments of 2 might be sensible for data structures with a lot of layers). For this you'll need to keep track of the indent-step as well as the total indentation amount.

---

```
if isinstance(obj, dict):
    start = '{'
    end = '}'
    for k, v in sorted(obj.items()):
        if not isinstance(v, supported):
            item = ' ' * indent + repr(k) + ': ' + repr(v)
        else:
            item = ' ' * indent + repr(k) + ': ' + represent(v, indent + 4)
        ls.append(item)
```

I don't see a particular reason to sort the key-value-pairs from the dictionary. On the contrary, since dicts in Python now preserve insertion order, this might actually change the data. So I'd drop the call to `sorted()` if you don't have an explicit reason for it.

---

I find this pattern

```
if not condition:
    # do A
else:
    # do B
```

to usually be better expressed as

```
if condition:
    # do B
else:
    # do A
```

or in your case:

```
for k, v in obj.items():
    if isinstance(v, supported):
        item = ' ' * indent + repr(k) + ': ' + represent(v, indent + 4)
    else:
        item = ' ' * indent + repr(k) + ': ' + repr(v)
    ls.append(item)
```

---

This whole snippet

```
enclosures = {
    0: ('frozenset({', '})'),
    1: '[]',
    2: '{}',
    3: '()'
}

index = 0
for i in singles:
    if isinstance(obj, i):
        break
    index += 1
start, end = enclosures[index]
```

is unnecessarily complicated, hard to read and rather un-pythonic. I see no particular reason to use indices instead of the types themselves:

```
enclosures = {
    frozenset: ('frozenset({', '})'),
    list: ('[', ']'),
    set: ('{', '}'),
    tuple: ('(', ')')
}

start, end = enclosures[type(obj)]
```

I would also remove this from the `elif`-case and add a dict-entry for `dict: ('{', '}')`, so you don't need to assign `start, end` in every case.

**EDIT:**
As correctly pointed out in the comments, this will not work for objects that are instances of subclasses of the supported classes.

The following adaptation will work, while still getting rid of the (otherwise meaningless) indices, thereby making the approach less error-prone:

```
for cls, enclosure in enclosures.items():
    if isinstance(obj, cls):
        start, end = enclosure
        break

# or

for cls in enclosures.keys():
    if isinstance(obj, cls):
        start, end = enclosures[cls]
        break
```

Another approach would be using

```
inspect.getmro(obj.__class__)
```

which returns a `tuple` of the object's class and all superclasses (in reverse hierarchical order as far as I can tell).

---

This code snippet should not check magic numbers:

```
if index in (0, 2):
    obj = sorted(obj)
```

Instead you should have a mapping of supported datatypes to a `sort` flag, which then decides if you sort the collection. Again, you should consider whether you actually need / want to sort these collections.

---

Most of your string assignments lend themselves nicely to using f-strings:

```
item = ' ' * indent + repr(k) + ': ' + represent(v, indent + 4)
```

becomes

```
item = f"{' ' * indent}{k!r}: {represent(v, indent + 4)}"
```

---

As of now you're explicitly checking and handling all supported datatypes in a single function. You might want to consider introducing seperate functions for different (kinds of) data types. This would make your main function more concise and easier to extend.

Comment: Your `enclosures[type(obj)]` will only work if objects are exactly the super types contained in the `dict`. Many objects are subclassed from the base classes,  for instance, `Counter` and `defaultdict` objects are instances of `dict`, but they aren't of the `dict` type, so trying to get the value using the type directly will very likely raise `KeyError`. And I did mention I use this function to serialize nested data structures, most frequently nested dictionary, and I always use `defaultdict` for convenience.

Comment: Yes, good point! I added an adjusted approach to my answer.

Comment: `f'{repr(k)}'` can be replaced with `f'{k!r}'`

Answer (score 5):

## Bugs

### Sets

Sets and dictionaries use identical delimiters: `{ ... }`.  Dictionaries are distinguished from sets by the presence of colon (`:`) separated key-value pairs.

Problem: Both an empty set and an empty dictionary are rendered by your code as `{}`.

```py
>>> eval(represent(set()))
{}

>>> eval(represent(set())) == set()
False
```

### Tuples

A tuple is a comma-separated list of values in parenthesis.

Problem: `(1)` is a Python expression evaluating to `1`, not a tuple; the Python syntax requires a trailing comma `(1,)` to ensure this is interpreted as a tuple.

```py
eval(represent((1,)))
1

eval(represent((1,))) == (1,)
False
```

## Conclusion

Your test cases are large, complex objects, but are missing important edge cases like:

- empty sets,
- empty tuples,
- single element tuples,
- string elements containing single & double quotes, backslashes,
- ...

Comment: Well, I have to admit these things do have a potential to cause problems, they can only cause minor problems. I can't imagine why anyone would want to use my function to dump those extremely simple objects as strings rather than use those short expressions directly, I intend my function to dump complex objects and it does that well, and clearly I can't cover all possible use cases...

Comment: A complex object may contain extremely simple elements, such as a dictionary of sets, where one of those sets happens to be empty, or a dictionary of tuples where some of those tuples might be of length 1.  In these cases an empty set would become an empty dictionary, which is not a problem if the recovered value is only read/tested and never modified.  The single element tuple becoming just the element is a problem, since a level of nesting has vanished, so code reading in the complex object will break using that element of the complex object.

Comment: *...clearly I can't cover all possible use cases...*. Those are not different use cases, but edge cases (as @AJNeufeld points out in his answer). Designing for certain use cases and therefore ignoring other cases is fine, while ignoring edge cases can (and will) usually lead to problems in most use cases.

Comment: Simple test cases are designed to ensure a failure in an edge case is understandable. I could have given `var = {(1,2): ({"doesn't work": set()},)}`, and `eval(represent(var)) == var` would return `False`, but it wouldn't be clear what the problem was. Is it the tuple used as the dictionary key, the tuple value, the string key with the embedded single quote, or the set value? `len(var[1,2][0]["doesn't work"])` is a valid expression, but with `res = eval(represent(var))` the equivalent expression `len(res[1,2][0]["doesn't work"])` raises an exception: bonus points if you can guess exactly what.