# Serializing (nested) data structures in a human-readable format with all bugs fixed

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel, serialization

See [Serializing (nested) data structures in a human-readable format](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/269214/serializing-nested-data-structures-in-a-human-readable-format) for more details.

This is the latest version, I have fixed all bugs and now this piece of code works completely as intended.

And I have added many more test cases. So far all tests are successful. I think I can't find an edge case that will cause the code to return wrong results now.

My code is now greatly improved than the original, but I am not fully satisfied with the current code yet. As this is code review and I have already received answers I can't update the code posted in the original question so I have to post a new question.

### Latest Version

```py
from typing import Union

def represent(obj: Union[dict, frozenset, list, set, tuple], indent: int=4) -> str:
    singles = (frozenset, list, set, tuple)
    supported = (dict, *singles)
    if not isinstance(obj, supported):
        raise TypeError('argument `obj` should be an instance of a built-in container data type')
    if not isinstance(indent, int):
        raise TypeError('argument `indent` should be an `int`')
    if indent <= 0:
        raise ValueError('argument `indent` should be greater than 0')
    if indent % 2:
        raise ValueError('argument `indent` should be a multiple of 2')
    increment = indent
    def worker(obj, indent, add_level=True, not_value=True):
        ls = list()
        indent_level = ' '*(indent-increment)
        open_indent = indent_level * add_level
        if not isinstance(obj, supported):
            return indent_level * not_value + repr(obj)
        enclosures = {
            dict: ('{', '}'),
            frozenset: ('frozenset({', '})'),
            list: ('[', ']'),
            set: ('{', '}'),
            tuple: ('(', ')')
        }
        singletons = {
            dict: 'dict()',
            frozenset: 'frozenset({})',
            list: '[]',
            set: 'set()',
            tuple: '()'
        }
        for cls in supported:
            if isinstance(obj, cls):
                if not obj:
                    return open_indent + singletons[cls]
                start, end = enclosures[cls]
                obj_cls = cls
                break
        start = open_indent + start
        if obj_cls in singles:
            single_tuple = (obj_cls == tuple and len(obj) == 1)
            for i in obj:
                item = worker(i, indent+increment)
                if single_tuple:
                    item += ','
                ls.append(item)
        else:
            for k, v in obj.items():
                item = f"{' '*indent}{repr(k)}: {worker(v, indent+increment, False, False)}"
                ls.append(item)
        return "{0}\n{1}\n{2}{3}".format(start, ',\n'.join(ls), indent_level, end)
    return worker(obj, indent)
```

### Test cases

```py
var = {1: {1: {1: {1: {1: {1: 0}, 2: 0}, 2: {1: 0}, 3: 0},
   2: {1: {1: 0}, 2: 0},
   3: {1: 0}},
  2: {1: {1: {1: 0}, 2: 0}, 2: {1: 0}, 3: 0},
  3: {1: {1: 0}, 2: 0}},
 2: {1: {1: {1: {1: 0}, 2: 0}, 2: {1: 0}, 3: 0},
  2: {1: {1: 0}, 2: 0},
  3: {1: 0}},
 3: {1: {1: {1: 0}, 2: 0}, 2: {1: 0}, 3: 0}}


repred = represent(var)
print(repred)

print(f'{(eval(repred) == var)=}')

var1 = {'a': {'a': {'a': [0, 0, 0], 'b': [0, 0, 1], 'c': [0, 0, 2]},
  'b': {'a': [0, 1, 0], 'b': [0, 1, 1], 'c': [0, 1, 2]},
  'c': {'a': [0, 2, 0], 'b': [0, 2, 1], 'c': [0, 2, 2]}},
 'b': {'a': {'a': [1, 0, 0], 'b': [1, 0, 1], 'c': [1, 0, 2]},
  'b': {'a': [1, 1, 0], 'b': [1, 1, 1], 'c': [1, 1, 2]},
  'c': {'a': [1, 2, 0], 'b': [1, 2, 1], 'c': [1, 2, 2]}},
 'c': {'a': {'a': [2, 0, 0], 'b': [2, 0, 1], 'c': [2, 0, 2]},
  'b': {'a': [2, 1, 0], 'b': [2, 1, 1], 'c': [2, 1, 2]},
  'c': {'a': [2, 2, 0], 'b': [2, 2, 1], 'c': [2, 2, 2]}}}

print(represent(var1))

var2 = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], 6, [7, 8, 9]]

print(represent(var2))

print(represent(set()))
print(represent(dict()))
print(represent((1,)))
print(represent(([1,2,3,[4,5,6,[7,8,9]]],)))
print(represent([(1,),(2,),(3,),[(4,),(5,),(6,),[(7,),(8,),(9,)]]]))
print(represent([{(1,),(2,),(3,)},{(4,),(5,),(6,)},{(7,),(8,),(9,)}]))
print(represent({0: {0: set()}}))
```

### Correct output

```
{
    1: {
        1: {
            1: {
                1: {
                    1: {
                        1: 0
                    },
                    2: 0
                },
                2: {
                    1: 0
                },
                3: 0
            },
            2: {
                1: {
                    1: 0
                },
                2: 0
            },
            3: {
                1: 0
            }
        },
        2: {
            1: {
                1: {
                    1: 0
                },
                2: 0
            },
            2: {
                1: 0
            },
            3: 0
        },
        3: {
            1: {
                1: 0
            },
            2: 0
        }
    },
    2: {
        1: {
            1: {
                1: {
                    1: 0
                },
                2: 0
            },
            2: {
                1: 0
            },
            3: 0
        },
        2: {
            1: {
                1: 0
            },
            2: 0
        },
        3: {
            1: 0
        }
    },
    3: {
        1: {
            1: {
                1: 0
            },
            2: 0
        },
        2: {
            1: 0
        },
        3: 0
    }
}
(eval(repred) == var)=True
{
    'a': {
        'a': {
            'a': [
                0,
                0,
                0
            ],
            'b': [
                0,
                0,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                0,
                0,
                2
            ]
        },
        'b': {
            'a': [
                0,
                1,
                0
            ],
            'b': [
                0,
                1,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                0,
                1,
                2
            ]
        },
        'c': {
            'a': [
                0,
                2,
                0
            ],
            'b': [
                0,
                2,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                0,
                2,
                2
            ]
        }
    },
    'b': {
        'a': {
            'a': [
                1,
                0,
                0
            ],
            'b': [
                1,
                0,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                1,
                0,
                2
            ]
        },
        'b': {
            'a': [
                1,
                1,
                0
            ],
            'b': [
                1,
                1,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                1,
                1,
                2
            ]
        },
        'c': {
            'a': [
                1,
                2,
                0
            ],
            'b': [
                1,
                2,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                1,
                2,
                2
            ]
        }
    },
    'c': {
        'a': {
            'a': [
                2,
                0,
                0
            ],
            'b': [
                2,
                0,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                2,
                0,
                2
            ]
        },
        'b': {
            'a': [
                2,
                1,
                0
            ],
            'b': [
                2,
                1,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                2,
                1,
                2
            ]
        },
        'c': {
            'a': [
                2,
                2,
                0
            ],
            'b': [
                2,
                2,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                2,
                2,
                2
            ]
        }
    }
}
[
    [
        0,
        1,
        2
    ],
    [
        3,
        4,
        5
    ],
    6,
    [
        7,
        8,
        9
    ]
]
set()
dict()
(
    1,
)
(
    [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        [
            4,
            5,
            6,
            [
                7,
                8,
                9
            ]
        ]
    ],
)
[
    (
        1,
    ),
    (
        2,
    ),
    (
        3,
    ),
    [
        (
            4,
        ),
        (
            5,
        ),
        (
            6,
        ),
        [
            (
                7,
            ),
            (
                8,
            ),
            (
                9,
            )
        ]
    ]
]
[
    {
        (
            1,
        ),
        (
            2,
        ),
        (
            3,
        )
    },
    {
        (
            6,
        ),
        (
            4,
        ),
        (
            5,
        )
    },
    {
        (
            7,
        ),
        (
            8,
        ),
        (
            9,
        )
    }
]
{
    0: {
        0: set()
    }
}
```

Please help me make it better!

### Edit

Well, I think I have made all the improvements I can make to the script now, I think I have done all possible improvements I can to the script now, so I will not edit this question again. What other improvements can be possibly made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## White space

53 lines without a blank line is excessive.  Add vertical white-space to break the function into logical chunks.  Validation, initialization, `worker`.  Same thing inside the `worker`.

## Type-hints

Depending on the version of Python you're targeting, you can remove `Unipn[...]`, and just use the "or" operator:

```py
def represent(obj: dict | frozenset | list | set | tuple, indent: int=4) -> str:
```

The `worker` could use type-hints too:

```py
    def worker(obj, indent: int, add_level: bool = True, not_value: bool = True) -> str:
```

## Multiplication by boolean?

`indent_level * add_level` and `indent_level * not_value`?  Those are booleans, not integers.  Yes, they can be interpreted as 0 and 1, but yuck!

## add_level and not_value?

What is `not_value`?  That name is quite obfuscating.  Moreover, you only ever call worker with the two parameters both defaulted to `True`, or both explicitly set to `False`.  Why two parameters then?

## local(local(local(local(...))))

```py
def represent(obj: Union[dict, frozenset, list, set, tuple], indent: int=4) -> str:
    ...
    supported = (dict, *singles)
    ...
    def worker(obj, indent, add_level=True, not_value=True):
        ...
        if not isinstance(obj, supported):
        ...
        enclosures = { ... }
        singletons = { ... }
```

You define `supported` in `represented` scope, and use it inside `worker` scope.  All is good.

But you **redefine** `enclosures` and `singletons` each and every time you recurse into a deeper level of `worker`.  This creates and recreates these variables on the stack at each level.  They are constants, and could easily be defined at `worker` scope, saving both execution time and memory.

As @riskypenguin said, you could move these out of `represent()` to a module-level constant, so they are created once instead of each time `represent()` is called.

## f-strings

`f"...{repr(k)}..."` could be written with the `!r` format code: `f"...{k!r}..."`

Indenting may be accomplished using field width specifiers.  As in `f"{'':{indent}}..."` instead of creating and recreating strings of spaces all the time.

## String concatenation

The code is constantly creating new strings and combining them using string concatenation (`+`) or `.join()` calls.  This probably has exponential time and space complexity as the nesting level increases.

Instead of concatenating strings, you should accumulate the output into one [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=stringio#io.StringIO) buffer, which is designed for constantly appending strings into a increasing blob of text.

### print_stdout

If the programmer overhead of using `string_buf.write(...)` or `print(..., file=string_buf)` is too high, you could just `print()` each string line to stdout.  Call that version of the function `print_represent(...)`.

Then you could write a wrapper function which returns the result as string using [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html?highlight=stringio#contextlib.redirect_stdout):

```py
def represent(obj: Union[dict, frozenset, list, set, tuple], indent: int=4) -> str:
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(io.StringIO()) as string_buf:
        print_represent(obj, indent)
    return string_buf.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 2):

This function is now considerably longer and harder to understand than before. I find nested functions (especially of this complexity) really harm readability, since you need to keep track of even more layers of context to understand the full functionality. I strongly suggest splitting this function into top-level functions to increase readability and seperate logic.

---

`singles`, `supported`, `enclosures`, `singletons` (not an accurate name by the way, [singleton pattern on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)) are basically collections of different attributes that could and should be contained within a single object. I suggest using a `collections.namedtuple`, but there are other approaches as well.

```
from typing import Union    
from collections import namedtuple

SupportedType = namedtuple("SupportedType", ["base_class", "enclosures", "empty_repr"])


def represent(obj: Union[dict, frozenset, list, set, tuple], indent: int = 4) -> str:
    supported_types = (
        SupportedType(base_class=dict, enclosures=('{', '}'), empty_repr='dict()'),
        SupportedType(base_class=list, enclosures=('[', ']'), empty_repr='[]'),
        SupportedType(base_class=set, enclosures=('{', '}'), empty_repr='set()'),
        SupportedType(base_class=tuple, enclosures=('{', '}'), empty_repr='()'),
        SupportedType(base_class=frozenset, enclosures=('frozenset({', '})'), empty_repr='frozenset()'),
    )

    for supported_type in supported_types:
        if isinstance(obj, supported_type.base_class):
            supported_base_class = supported_type.base_class
            start, end = supported_type.enclosures
            empty_repr = supported_type.empty_repr
            break
    else:
        raise TypeError('argument `obj` should be an instance of a built-in container data type')

    ...
```

This way you have all the relevant information regarding your supported types in proper context and can get rid of the multiple `isinstance` checks. You could extend this to also make each instance of SupportedType contain a reference to the correct `represent_object_of_type` (or similiar) function. This lets you get rid of un-elegant (hardcoded) checks like `isinstance(obj, dict)`.

`supported_types` should also move to a module-level constant (if that makes sense for your project).