# Python functions to serialize nested data structures human readably

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, programming-challenge, serialization

See [Serializing (nested) data structures in a human-readable format](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/269214/serializing-nested-data-structures-in-a-human-readable-format) for more details.

In the last two days I have significantly improved my function, and wrote seven implementations of it.

I have written an updated version of the original function, updated function with `list` appending replaced by list comprehension, and the updated version with string concatenation and joining replaced by `StringIO` operations, `StringIO` version with `StringIO` api replaced by that of `deque` and `list`.

All the first five functions do not contain trailing commas.

I have also written a alternate version of the `StringIO` version with recursive generator functions, and an version of the `deque` version that allows trailing commas, both of the above contain trailing commas.

### Code

```py
import json
from collections import deque
from io import StringIO
from typing import Any, Union

SUPPORTED_TYPES = {
    dict: {'enclosures': ('{', '}'), 'empty_repr': 'dict()'},
    list: {'enclosures': ('[', ']'), 'empty_repr': '[]'},
    set: {'enclosures': ('{', '}'), 'empty_repr': 'set()'},
    tuple: {'enclosures': ('(', ')'), 'empty_repr': '()'},
    deque: {'enclosures': ('deque([', '])'), 'empty_repr': 'deque()'},
    frozenset: {'enclosures': ('frozenset({', '})'), 'empty_repr': 'frozenset()'},
}

def identify(obj: Any) -> type:
    base = obj.__class__.__mro__[-2]
    if base in SUPPORTED_TYPES:
        return base
    return None

def represent(obj: Union[deque, dict, frozenset, list, set, tuple], indent: int=4) -> str:
    if not identify(obj):
        raise TypeError('argument `obj` should be an instance of a built-in container data type (or `deque`)')
    if not isinstance(indent, int):
        raise TypeError('argument `indent` should be an `int`')
    if indent <= 0:
        raise ValueError('argument `indent` should be greater than 0')
    if indent % 2:
        raise ValueError('argument `indent` should be a multiple of 2')
    increment = ' '*indent
    
    def mapping_worker(obj: dict, indent: str, indent_level: str, top_indent: str) -> str:
        ls = list()
        start = top_indent+'{'
        for k, v in obj.items():
            ls.append(indent+f'{k!r}: '+overseer(v, indent+increment, indent, ''))
        return start+'\n'+',\n'.join(ls)+'\n'+indent_level+'}'
    
    def sequence_worker(obj: Union[deque, frozenset, list, set, tuple], indent: str, indent_level: str,
            top_indent: str, start: str, end: str, single_tuple: bool) -> str:
        start = top_indent+start
        if single_tuple:
            item = overseer(obj[0], indent+increment, indent, indent)
            return start+'\n'+item+',\n'+indent_level+end
        ls = list()
        for i in obj:
            ls.append(overseer(i, indent+increment, indent, indent))
        return start+'\n'+',\n'.join(ls)+'\n'+indent_level+end
    
    def overseer(obj: Any, indent: str,
                indent_level: str, top_indent: str) -> str:
        identified = identify(obj)
        if not identified:
            return top_indent+f'{obj!r}'
        if not obj:
            return top_indent+SUPPORTED_TYPES[identified]['empty_repr']
        if identified == dict:
            return mapping_worker(obj, indent, indent_level, top_indent)
        start, end = SUPPORTED_TYPES[identified]['enclosures']
        single_tuple = (identified == tuple and len(obj) == 1)
        return sequence_worker(obj, indent, indent_level, top_indent, start, end, single_tuple)
    
    return overseer(obj, ' '*indent, '', '')


def buffered_represent(obj: Union[deque, dict, frozenset, list, set, tuple], indent: int=4) -> str:
    if not identify(obj):
        raise TypeError('argument `obj` should be an instance of a built-in container data type (or `deque`)')
    if not isinstance(indent, int):
        raise TypeError('argument `indent` should be an `int`')
    if indent <= 0:
        raise ValueError('argument `indent` should be greater than 0')
    if indent % 2:
        raise ValueError('argument `indent` should be a multiple of 2')
    increment = ' '*indent
    
    def mapping_worker(obj: dict, indent: str, indent_level: str, top_indent: str) -> str:
        buffer.write(top_indent+'{\n')
        for k, v in obj.items():
            buffer.write(indent+f'{k!r}: ')
            overseer(v, indent+increment, indent, '')
            buffer.write(',\n')
        buffer.seek(buffer.tell() - 2)
        buffer.write('\n'+indent_level+'}')
    
    def sequence_worker(obj: Union[deque, frozenset, list, set, tuple], indent: str, indent_level: str,
            top_indent: str, start: str, end: str, single_tuple: bool) -> str:
        buffer.write(top_indent+start+'\n')
        if single_tuple:
            overseer(obj[0], indent+increment, indent, indent)
            return buffer.write(',\n'+indent_level+end)
        for i in obj:
            overseer(i, indent+increment, indent, indent)
            buffer.write(',\n')
        buffer.seek(buffer.tell() - 2)
        buffer.write('\n'+indent_level+end)
    
    def overseer(obj: Any, indent: str,
                indent_level: str, top_indent: str) -> str:
        identified = identify(obj)
        if not identified:
            return buffer.write(top_indent+f'{obj!r}')
        if not obj:
            return buffer.write(top_indent+SUPPORTED_TYPES[identified]['empty_repr'])
        if identified == dict:
            return mapping_worker(obj, indent, indent_level, top_indent)
        start, end = SUPPORTED_TYPES[identified]['enclosures']
        single_tuple = (identified == tuple and len(obj) == 1)
        sequence_worker(obj, indent, indent_level, top_indent, start, end, single_tuple)
    with StringIO() as buffer:
        overseer(obj, ' '*indent, '', '')
        return buffer.getvalue()


def deque_represent(obj: Union[deque, dict, frozenset, list, set, tuple], indent: int=4) -> str:
    if not identify(obj):
        raise TypeError('argument `obj` should be an instance of a built-in container data type (or `deque`)')
    if not isinstance(indent, int):
        raise TypeError('argument `indent` should be an `int`')
    if indent <= 0:
        raise ValueError('argument `indent` should be greater than 0')
    if indent % 2:
        raise ValueError('argument `indent` should be a multiple of 2')
    increment = ' '*indent
    buffer = deque()
    def mapping_worker(obj: dict, indent: str, indent_level: str, top_indent: str) -> str:
        buffer.append(top_indent+'{\n')
        for k, v in obj.items():
            buffer.append(indent+f'{k!r}: ')
            overseer(v, indent+increment, indent, '')
            buffer.append(',\n')
        buffer.pop()
        buffer.append('\n'+indent_level+'}')
    
    def sequence_worker(obj: Union[deque, frozenset, list, set, tuple], indent: str, indent_level: str,
            top_indent: str, start: str, end: str, single_tuple: bool) -> str:
        buffer.append(top_indent+start+'\n')
        if single_tuple:
            overseer(obj[0], indent+increment, indent, indent)
            return buffer.append(',\n'+indent_level+end)
        for i in obj:
            overseer(i, indent+increment, indent, indent)
            buffer.append(',\n')
        buffer.pop()
        buffer.append('\n'+indent_level+end)
    
    def overseer(obj: Any, indent: str,
                indent_level: str, top_indent: str) -> str:
        identified = identify(obj)
        if not identified:
            return buffer.append(top_indent+f'{obj!r}')
        if not obj:
            return buffer.append(top_indent+SUPPORTED_TYPES[identified]['empty_repr'])
        if identified == dict:
            return mapping_worker(obj, indent, indent_level, top_indent)
        start, end = SUPPORTED_TYPES[identified]['enclosures']
        single_tuple = (identified == tuple and len(obj) == 1)
        sequence_worker(obj, indent, indent_level, top_indent, start, end, single_tuple)
    
    overseer(obj, ' '*indent, '', '')
    return ''.join(buffer)


def list_represent(obj: Union[deque, dict, frozenset, list, set, tuple], indent: int=4) -> str:
    if not identify(obj):
        raise TypeError('argument `obj` should be an instance of a built-in container data type (or `deque`)')
    if not isinstance(indent, int):
        raise TypeError('argument `indent` should be an `int`')
    if indent <= 0:
        raise ValueError('argument `indent` should be greater than 0')
    if indent % 2:
        raise ValueError('argument `indent` should be a multiple of 2')
    increment = ' '*indent
    buffer = list()
    def mapping_worker(obj: dict, indent: str, indent_level: str, top_indent: str) -> str:
        buffer.append(top_indent+'{\n')
        for k, v in obj.items():
            buffer.append(indent+f'{k!r}: ')
            overseer(v, indent+increment, indent, '')
            buffer.append(',\n')
        buffer.pop(-1)
        buffer.append('\n'+indent_level+'}')
    
    def sequence_worker(obj: Union[deque, frozenset, list, set, tuple], indent: str, indent_level: str,
            top_indent: str, start: str, end: str, single_tuple: bool) -> str:
        buffer.append(top_indent+start+'\n')
        if single_tuple:
            overseer(obj[0], indent+increment, indent, indent)
            return buffer.append(',\n'+indent_level+end)
        for i in obj:
            overseer(i, indent+increment, indent, indent)
            buffer.append(',\n')
        buffer.pop(-1)
        buffer.append('\n'+indent_level+end)
    
    def overseer(obj: Any, indent: str,
                indent_level: str, top_indent: str) -> str:
        identified = identify(obj)
        if not identified:
            return buffer.append(top_indent+f'{obj!r}')
        if not obj:
            return buffer.append(top_indent+SUPPORTED_TYPES[identified]['empty_repr'])
        if identified == dict:
            return mapping_worker(obj, indent, indent_level, top_indent)
        start, end = SUPPORTED_TYPES[identified]['enclosures']
        single_tuple = (identified == tuple and len(obj) == 1)
        sequence_worker(obj, indent, indent_level, top_indent, start, end, single_tuple)
    
    overseer(obj, ' '*indent, '', '')
    return ''.join(buffer)


def listcomp_represent(obj: Union[deque, dict, frozenset, list, set, tuple], indent: int=4) -> str:
    if not identify(obj):
        raise TypeError('argument `obj` should be an instance of a built-in container data type (or `deque`)')
    if not isinstance(indent, int):
        raise TypeError('argument `indent` should be an `int`')
    if indent <= 0:
        raise ValueError('argument `indent` should be greater than 0')
    if indent % 2:
        raise ValueError('argument `indent` should be a multiple of 2')
    increment = ' '*indent
    
    def mapping_worker(obj: dict, indent: str, indent_level: str, top_indent: str) -> str:
        start = top_indent+'{'
        ls = [indent+f'{k!r}: '+overseer(v, indent+increment, indent, '') for k, v in obj.items()]
        return start+'\n'+',\n'.join(ls)+'\n'+indent_level+'}'
    
    def sequence_worker(obj: Union[deque, frozenset, list, set, tuple], indent: str, indent_level: str,
            top_indent: str, start: str, end: str, single_tuple: bool) -> str:
        start = top_indent+start
        if single_tuple:
            item = overseer(obj[0], indent+increment, indent, indent)
            return start+'\n'+item+',\n'+indent_level+end
        ls = [overseer(i, indent+increment, indent, indent) for i in obj]
        return start+'\n'+',\n'.join(ls)+'\n'+indent_level+end
    
    def overseer(obj: Any, indent: str,
                indent_level: str, top_indent: str) -> str:
        identified = identify(obj)
        if not identified:
            return top_indent+f'{obj!r}'
        if not obj:
            return top_indent+SUPPORTED_TYPES[identified]['empty_repr']
        if identified == dict:
            return mapping_worker(obj, indent, indent_level, top_indent)
        start, end = SUPPORTED_TYPES[identified]['enclosures']
        single_tuple = (identified == tuple and len(obj) == 1)
        return sequence_worker(obj, indent, indent_level, top_indent, start, end, single_tuple)
    
    return overseer(obj, ' '*indent, '', '')

def generator_represent(obj: Union[deque, dict, frozenset, list, set, tuple], indent: int=4) -> str:
    if not identify(obj):
        raise TypeError('argument `obj` should be an instance of a built-in container data type (or `deque`)')
    if not isinstance(indent, int):
        raise TypeError('argument `indent` should be an `int`')
    if indent <= 0:
        raise ValueError('argument `indent` should be greater than 0')
    if indent % 2:
        raise ValueError('argument `indent` should be a multiple of 2')
    increment = ' '*indent

    def mapping_worker(obj: dict, indent: str, indent_level: str, top_indent: str) -> str:
        yield top_indent+'{\n'
        for k, v in obj.items():
            yield indent+f'{k!r}: '
            yield from overseer(v, indent+increment, indent, '')
            yield ',\n'
        yield indent_level+'}'
    
    def sequence_worker(obj: Union[deque, frozenset, list, set, tuple], indent: str, indent_level: str,
            top_indent: str, start: str, end: str) -> str:
        yield top_indent+start+'\n'
        for i in obj:
            yield from overseer(i, indent+increment, indent, indent)
            yield ',\n'
        yield indent_level+end
    
    def overseer(obj: Any, indent: str,
                indent_level: str, top_indent: str) -> str:
        identified = identify(obj)
        if not identified:
           return top_indent+f'{obj!r}'
        if not obj:
            return top_indent+SUPPORTED_TYPES[identified]['empty_repr']
        if identified == dict:
            return mapping_worker(obj, indent, indent_level, top_indent)
        start, end = SUPPORTED_TYPES[identified]['enclosures']
        return sequence_worker(obj, indent, indent_level, top_indent, start, end)
    
    return ''.join(overseer(obj, ' '*indent, '', ''))

def deque_represent_with_trail(obj: Union[deque, dict, frozenset, list, set, tuple], indent: int=4) -> str:
    if not identify(obj):
        raise TypeError('argument `obj` should be an instance of a built-in container data type (or `deque`)')
    if not isinstance(indent, int):
        raise TypeError('argument `indent` should be an `int`')
    if indent <= 0:
        raise ValueError('argument `indent` should be greater than 0')
    if indent % 2:
        raise ValueError('argument `indent` should be a multiple of 2')
    increment = ' '*indent
    buffer = deque()
    def mapping_worker(obj: dict, indent: str, indent_level: str, top_indent: str) -> str:
        buffer.append(top_indent+'{\n')
        for k, v in obj.items():
            buffer.append(indent+f'{k!r}: ')
            overseer(v, indent+increment, indent, '')
            buffer.append(',\n')
        buffer.append(indent_level+'}')
    
    def sequence_worker(obj: Union[deque, frozenset, list, set, tuple], indent: str, indent_level: str,
            top_indent: str, start: str, end: str) -> str:
        buffer.append(top_indent+start+'\n')
        for i in obj:
            overseer(i, indent+increment, indent, indent)
            buffer.append(',\n')
        buffer.append(indent_level+end)
    
    def overseer(obj: Any, indent: str,
                indent_level: str, top_indent: str) -> str:
        identified = identify(obj)
        if not identified:
            return buffer.append(top_indent+f'{obj!r}')
        if not obj:
            return buffer.append(top_indent+SUPPORTED_TYPES[identified]['empty_repr'])
        if identified == dict:
            return mapping_worker(obj, indent, indent_level, top_indent)
        start, end = SUPPORTED_TYPES[identified]['enclosures']
        sequence_worker(obj, indent, indent_level, top_indent, start, end)
    
    overseer(obj, ' '*indent, '', '')
    return ''.join(buffer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    var = {'a': {'a': {'a': [0, 0, 0], 'b': [0, 0, 1], 'c': [0, 0, 2]},
      'b': {'a': [0, 1, 0], 'b': [0, 1, 1], 'c': [0, 1, 2]},
      'c': {'a': [0, 2, 0], 'b': [0, 2, 1], 'c': [0, 2, 2]}},
     'b': {'a': {'a': [1, 0, 0], 'b': [1, 0, 1], 'c': [1, 0, 2]},
      'b': {'a': [1, 1, 0], 'b': [1, 1, 1], 'c': [1, 1, 2]},
      'c': {'a': [1, 2, 0], 'b': [1, 2, 1], 'c': [1, 2, 2]}},
     'c': {'a': {'a': [2, 0, 0], 'b': [2, 0, 1], 'c': [2, 0, 2]},
      'b': {'a': [2, 1, 0], 'b': [2, 1, 1], 'c': [2, 1, 2]},
      'c': {'a': [2, 2, 0], 'b': [2, 2, 1], 'c': [2, 2, 2]}}}

    repr0 = represent(var)
    print(repr0)
    assert eval(repr0) == var
    repr1 = buffered_represent(var)
    repr2 = deque_represent(var)
    repr3 = list_represent(var)
    repr4 = listcomp_represent(var)
    repr5 = generator_represent(var)
    repr6 = deque_represent_with_trail(var)
    assert len({repr0, repr1, repr2, repr3, repr4}) == 1
    assert repr5 == repr6
```

Output:

```py
{
    'a': {
        'a': {
            'a': [
                0,
                0,
                0
            ],
            'b': [
                0,
                0,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                0,
                0,
                2
            ]
        },
        'b': {
            'a': [
                0,
                1,
                0
            ],
            'b': [
                0,
                1,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                0,
                1,
                2
            ]
        },
        'c': {
            'a': [
                0,
                2,
                0
            ],
            'b': [
                0,
                2,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                0,
                2,
                2
            ]
        }
    },
    'b': {
        'a': {
            'a': [
                1,
                0,
                0
            ],
            'b': [
                1,
                0,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                1,
                0,
                2
            ]
        },
        'b': {
            'a': [
                1,
                1,
                0
            ],
            'b': [
                1,
                1,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                1,
                1,
                2
            ]
        },
        'c': {
            'a': [
                1,
                2,
                0
            ],
            'b': [
                1,
                2,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                1,
                2,
                2
            ]
        }
    },
    'c': {
        'a': {
            'a': [
                2,
                0,
                0
            ],
            'b': [
                2,
                0,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                2,
                0,
                2
            ]
        },
        'b': {
            'a': [
                2,
                1,
                0
            ],
            'b': [
                2,
                1,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                2,
                1,
                2
            ]
        },
        'c': {
            'a': [
                2,
                2,
                0
            ],
            'b': [
                2,
                2,
                1
            ],
            'c': [
                2,
                2,
                2
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Needless to say all assertions succeeded, you can also test examples from [Serializing (nested) data structures in a human-readable format with all bugs fixed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/269247/serializing-nested-data-structures-in-a-human-readable-format-with-all-bugs-fi).

All the functions support `deque, dict, frozenset, list, set, tuple`, and through `dict`, `Counter`, `OrderedDict`, and `defaultdict`, and through `tuple`, support `namedtuple` to a lesser extent (`namedtuple`s are treated as base `tuple`s so field names are lost).

### Performance

```
In [2]: %timeit json.dumps(var)
27 µs ± 3.87 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit represent(var)
123 µs ± 3.81 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit listcomp_represent(var)
127 µs ± 3.13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit deque_represent(var)
125 µs ± 3.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit list_represent(var)
127 µs ± 2.61 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit buffered_represent(var)
148 µs ± 4.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [8]: %timeit generator_represent(var)
328 µs ± 31.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [9]: %timeit deque_represent_with_trail(var)
118 µs ± 2.45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Needless to say, `json.dumps` is the fastest, and also needless to say `json` supports far less data types (more specifically, it can't serialize `set`, `deque` and `frozenset`, and after serializing and deserializing `tuple`s will become `list`s), but it is really fast.

Of the functions that support all the data types, of the functions that eliminate trailing commas, sometimes `represent` is the fastest, sometimes `deque_represent` is as fast as represent. I can't decide which is more performant.

`list_represent` is consistently a little slower than `deque_represent`, and surprisingly, the first function with list comp is a little slower and I don't know why.
I have also tried to replace the `list`s in the first version with `deque`s and strangely it slows the execution down.

The version using `StringIO` is noticeably slower than the above functions and I really don't know why.

The version using generators is significantly slower than all other functions and I really can't explain this, how can it be slower if it doesn't even initialize a collection variable and append strings to that collection?

Of all functions I have written, the `deque` with trailing commas is the fastest, but it allows trailing commas and the performance gain is minimal. And removing trailing commas using `re` is not a good idea since single element `tuple`s need trailing commas the regex need to be more complex than necessary.

Which function is the best overall? I think the `deque` version is the most performant but I am not sure. And as you can see I really do care about performance, how can I improve the functions to reach `json` level performance? And what Python collection data type appends even faster than `deque`? I tried to Google Search for this, of course, and unsurprisingly all results are completely irrelevant.

### Update

I poked around the source code of `json` ('C:\Program Files\Python39\Lib\json') a bit and tried to rewrite it to modify its features and discovered that it imports the built-in module `_json`, and uses the `make_encoder` function to make a default `_json.Encoder` class object to encode objects without indentation, and it uses Python functions to serialize objects with indentation.

The default function calls to `json.dump(s)` without specifying indent, the `indent` argument is `None` and `json` module cheats by using the `_json` module which is written in C, and C is indeed fast, being precompiled, but the output is quite ugly.

For any function calls that specify indent, `json` instead uses the Python functions which are not as performant because of interpreted nature, and the runtime is longer.

In short calling `json.dumps` without setting a non-zero indent, `json` cheats by use precompiled C code to leverage its speed, but it is not "Pure Python", serializing objects with indentation instead makes it fall back to pure Python functions and revealing its low performance nature.

My tests were unscientific because I didn't specify indent when calling `json.dumps(var)` and in fact only tested optimized precompiled C code, testing with indentation to test the real Python code though...

```
In [177]: %timeit json.dumps(var)
29 µs ± 3.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [178]: %timeit json.dumps(var,indent=4)
169 µs ± 5.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

It is slower than most of my custom functions and even slower than `StringIO` version, the only custom function slower than `json.dumps` is the recursive generator version, which, to be fair, is really bad written, because I don't normally write recursive generator functions and that one is the first, not to mention I don't often use generator functions to begin with, always opting to use `list`(`dict`, `set`...) comprehension because of performance (in short I most frequently use generator expressions in quotes and don't use the `yield` keyword as often).

So my functions indeed beat `json` at performance.

Comment: add a timeit response for `prettyprint`?